# Can someone die of hypothermia just from thinking they're in a cold place?

Tags: biology

There's a legend about a guy named Nick Sitzman who was accidentally locked in an unplugged walk in freezer.  It was during the summer so it was actually hot, but he thought the freezer was on, and he ended up dying of hypothermia because he thought the freezer was on. Before he died he used a rock or something to carve messages.

Is this actually possible?

There's something called [voodoo death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_death), but nothing about it causing hypothermia.

I originally read the story on Snopes, which does not confirm or deny the story: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/deadly-imaginings/

Comment: You can freeze to death at 50 degrees depending on the conditions, but I doubt those conditions would be present in a walk-in freezer. Seems more likely a person in such a situation might suffocate.

Comment: This was addressed under [another question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/43106/37236): Snopes says there's no evidence of this or similar stories actually happening.

Comment: Given that freezers are air-tight, or they wouldn't work very well, isn't the simplest explanation that the guy ran out of air?